# 'va_start' used in function with fixed args error

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-functions, ndk-build

My nullPointcheck function:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
bool __nullPointCheck(T first, Args... args)
{
    bool ret = true;
    va_list vl;
    auto n = sizeof...(args);
    va_start(vl, n);
    for (auto i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        auto p = va_arg(vl, T);
        if (!p)
        {
            ret = false;
        }
    }
    va_end(vl);
    return ret;
}
```

but I'm getting the ndk build error as follows:

```
'va_start' used in function with fixed args
va_start(vl, n);
```

when I change the second param in va_start to first as follows:

```
va_start(vl, first);
```

ndk-build export the error as follows:

```
     'va_start' used in function with fixed args
    va_start(vl, first);
    ^
E:/ANDROID_HOME/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/llvm-3.5/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin
\..\lib\clang\3.5\include\stdarg.h:33:29: note:
expanded from macro 'va_start'
#define va_start(ap, param) __builtin_va_start(ap, param)
```

There are no errors in vs2013, but the code can's pass ndk-build stage

Comment: a variadic template isn't the same what the old c vararg list function. do you want something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e69bba38673a8cd3) ?

Comment: [OT]: `__nullPointCheck` is a reserved identifier

Comment: By removing all va_list related code, I finally get my code passed with the help of parameter pack like this: std::array<T, N> arr = { params... } and iterate the array in a loop. But I have learnt a lot from your answer. @ Piotr Skotnicki Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`va_start` etc. can only be used in a function whose prototype ends in `...);` . This is different to a parameter pack. Your code uses a parameter pack. The syntax for using parameter packs is different to the syntax for variadic functions.

I am assuming your function should return `true` if and only if all arguments are non-null pointers. One way to implement your function would be:

```
inline constexpr bool nullPointCheck() { return true; }

template<typename T, typename... Args>
constexpr bool nullPointCheck(T&& first, Args&&... args)
{
    return first && nullPointCheck(args...);
}
```

rontgen's answer is also good.

---

You can actually use this function to check if any arbitrary argument list is all `true`. I used universal references so that copies are not made of the arguments; this makes no difference for pointers but may make a difference for more complicated types.

To limit the function to only accept pointers, change `T&&` to `T *`. (Leave `Args&&` as it is).  If you also want to accept the literal `nullptr` then you also need an overload:

```
inline constexpr bool nullPointCheck(std::nullptr_t) { return false; }
```

because `nullptr` actually does not deduce to any `T *`.

Answer (score 1):

My solusion which can pass the stage of compilation is as follows:

```
template<typename T, typename... Params, std::size_t N = sizeof...(Params)>
static bool nullPointCheck(Params... params)
{
    std::array<T, N> arr = { params... };
    for (auto point : arr)
    {
        if (!point)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You may as well `return false;` instead of `ret = false`. Also it doesn't make any sense for a function template to be `static`

Comment: @ M.M. Thanks for your advice. I will fix it.